# Datatables "Cannot read property sError of null"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm pretty new to datatables and I need to load the data into the table using AJAX server processing.

I tried using GET request but I received a 404 not found error, and the URL was incomplete (the action name was missing from the URL).

I read a post for a similar problem recommending using POST instead of GET request. Using GET I now receive the "Cannot read property sError of null", and can't figure out what happens.

I can't get to debug in the controller, since it doesn't even get there.

Here is my initalization code for the datatables object:

```
 oTable = $('#solutionsTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bSort": false,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
        },
        "bProcessing": true,
        // "bDeferRender": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bAjaxSource": "AJAXGetUserData",
        "sServerMethod": "POST"
    });
```

and this is the controller action (although it doesn't get there)

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AJAXGetUserData(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    { 
        var allUsers = CMSHelper.GetUsers(countries: User.IsInRole("Account Admin") ? CMSHelper.GetAdminCountries(User.Identity.Name).Select(c => c.Key).ToList() : null);
        var result = from u in allUsers 
                     select new string[] {Convert.ToString(u.userId), u.userName, u.roleId.ToString(), u.type, u.isActive.ToString(), u.firstName, u.lastName, 
                     u.email, u.phone, u.Postcode, u.Street, u.Street, u.company, u.jobId.ToString(), u.job, u.country, u.countryName, u.City, u.LoginsNum.ToString(), 
                     u.LastLogin.ToShortDateString()};

        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = 97,
            iTotalDisplayRecords = 3,
            aaData = result
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was returning actually a 404 Not found exception, which was not caught because my action used POST request and the PageNotFound action in my Home Controller was targeted to GET requests only. Although I can't figure it out why I get the Not Found Response